# Split programatically a specific row in two columns in XAML

Tags: c#, xaml

[image: Grid view]

The picture represents a grid. The first row (Row 0) is hard-coded in XAML file. I am creating the second row programmatically.

After that, I am adding another two columns programmatically in order to divide the second row (Row 1).

The columns will be added for the whole Grid and will divide Row 0 as well.

How to split only Row 1?

Comment: You could try not using columns, instead maybe try inserting a grid as row 1 and split only that grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Grid.ColumnSpan = 2 and Grid.Row = 0 in The element you put in the grid (stackpanel for example).

Comment: Your comment was very helpful. The following line did the trick.                                     Grid.SetColumnSpan(<name of the stackpanel>, 2);